# Reset variables and entire class

Tags: java, class, variables

I am making a java black jack game, and I need the class that handles each new round to be reset every time I call it (every new round that is). The class has these variables:

```
public static LinkedList<String> playerHand = new LinkedList<>(), dealerHand = new LinkedList<>(); // creates hands for player and dealer
public static int playerValue, dealerValue; // value of the hand
```

This is how I summon this class, from my main class:

```
gameplay.NewRound.newHand(s);
```

'gameplay' is the java package, 'NewRound' is the class, 'newHand' is the void that starts the gameplay, and 's' is the bet.

My question is, will the class reset, like the hand values and linkedlists ect... if I keep calling it like this? Or would I have to add a MAIN in the NewRound class and call it like this:

```
new gameplay.NewRound();
```

Comment: The easiest way is to create a new instance of the class. Don't worry for the *wasted* memory usage, that's GC's work.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza so the way I have it in the last line of the post would do as I wanted?

Comment: If your `NewRound` constructor already has the necessary data to start all over again, then it should work.

Comment: I think the first method should work without resetting the values. Why don't you just test it out?

Comment: @usama8800 I need the variables to reset everytime

Answer (score 0):

**To your question**: there is no built-in way to "reset" an existing instance of a class, unless you have implemented a method, which does this. Most often you just create a new instance and the garbage collector cares about freeing the memory from the unused object. There are certain cases, when you would prefer to implement "reset" behavior: object creation is too expensive or some business logic requires only a certain amount of existing instance.

Basically, the best approach to make your code elegant and readable is making it replicate the behavior of the domain objects.

My suggestion is: an instance of `Game` class, which will keep the track of the whole game.  Also this `Game` will have a method to create `NewRound`, which will return a fully clean instance of `NewRound`

```
`
public class Game{
    private List<Round> roundList = new LinkedList<Round>();
    public Round startNewRound(int bet){
        Round newRound = new Round(bet);
        this.roundList.add(newRound);
        return newRound;
    }
}

public class Round{
    public List<String> dealerHand;
    public List<String> playerHand;
    public int bet;
    public Round(int bet){
        this.dealerHand = new LinkedList<String>();
        this.playerHand = new LinkedList<String>();
        this.bet = bet
    }
    public String compareHands(){
        //Some comparison between hands, return "dealer" or "player"
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Game game = new Game();
    Round roundOne = game.startNewRound(1);
    roundOne.dealerHand.add("Ace Of Spades");
    roundOne.playerHand.add("Some other card");
    System.out.println(roundOne.compareHands+" wins!");
    Round roundTwo = game.startNewRound(4);
    roundTwo.dealerHand.add("Another Ace Of Spades");
    roundTwo.playerHand.add("Some other stupid card");
    System.out.println(roundTwo.compareHands+" wins!");
}
```

`